# time format not changing in timepicker kotlin

Tags: kotlin, format, timepicker

So I used a timepicker in android studio Kotlin to receive input from the user as the following:

`

```
private lateinit var editTime : TimePicker
```

`

I did create the timepicker successfully, but whenever I show the result in a recyclerview the format **is as the following:

0:4

which actually is

12:04 AM

I don't know how to change the format, I tried this:

```
       var hour = editTime.hour.toString().format("%02d")
        val minute = editTime.minute.toString().format("%02d")
```

but it only worked with a timepicker dialog not the widget one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
var hour = String.format("%02d", editTime.hour)
var min = String.format("%02d", editTime.minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to convert hour and minute into required format

```
    fun getTimeString(hour: Int, minute: Int): String {
        val time = LocalTime.of(hour, minute)
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a")
        return time.format(formatter)
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work, but aimen izhar's answer did. Thanks anyway!